# Log a value to the console using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

All I want to do is make sure that jQuery is getting the right value from an input for each row. What am I missing?

```js
function shortDescription() {
  $(function() {
    var tbl = $(document.getElementById('21.125-mrss-cont-none-content'));
    tbl.find('tr').each(function() {
      $(this).find("input[name$='6#if']").keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
          var input = $(this).val();
          $(this).val(input);
          console.log(input);
        }
      });
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Look in the console.
<table id="21.125-mrss-cont-none-content">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name='6#if' />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Well there's no `console.log` call in your code for starters. Where are you calling `shortDescription()` from? You don't need the document.ready event handler within the `shortDescription()` function, nor the `each()` loop. To help you find a solution it would help to see your HTML.

Comment: It's being called from an oninput in an input element. I know it works because I've used a similar function to calculate data and convert text. Not getting any value to the console.

Comment: Include the call to the function in your sample code.  I tried this script out as it is by calling shortDescription() directly, and it worked fine (assuming that what you want it to do is console.log the field content after pressing return, which is what your script does) -- your problem could be with how the script is being initiated.

Comment: It works now. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make it simpler

```
function shortDescription() {
  var table = document.getElementById('21.125-mrss-cont-none-content');
  $(table).find("input[name$='6#if']").keypress(function( e ) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      var input = $(this).val();
      $(this).val(input);
      console.log(input);
    }
  });
 }
```

Can test here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nbx6j7zo/)

Answer (score -1):

```js
function shortDescription() {
  $(function() {
    var tbl = $(document.getElementById('21.125-mrss-cont-none-content'));
    tbl.find('tr').each(function() {
      $(this).find("input[name$='6#if']").keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
          var input = $(this).val();

          console.log(input);

          $(this).val(input);
        }
      });
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Look in the console.
<table id="21.125-mrss-cont-none-content">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name='6#if' />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```